# Знаки препинания при пояснении

Tags: пунктуация

Требуются ли знаки препинания (после "оно") в предложениях типа "Вот оно отмщение оскорблённой душе"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно, знак препинания требуется — обособление **приложения** запятой.

***Вот оно, отмщение оскорблённой душе.***

**Приложение** — это определение, которое выражено существительным. Приложение по-новому характеризует предмет, дает ему другое название или указывает на степень родства, национальность, звание, профессию и т. д. Приложение всегда употребляется в том же падеже, что и существительное, к которому оно относится.

Если приложение относится к личному местоимению, то оно обособляется в любом случае, вне зависимости от места в предложении.
*Мы, еще совсем дети, тогда не понимали его.*
*Вот оно, объяснение* (Л. Толстой).
***Вот оно, отмщение за мое поруганное тело!*** (А. Махавкин)

P. S. Стоит отметить, что в предложениях, подобных Вашему, возможна двоякая пунктуация — в зависимости от характера **интонации, наличия или отсутствия паузы** после местоимения **3-го лица** (в указательной функции) с предшествующей частицей **вот**:
*Вот они, заячьи-то мечты! Вот они, работнички!

Вот она действительность-то. Вот оно торжество добродетели и правды.*
[Обособленные приложения](http://lingvotech.com/op)

P. P. S. Мне Ваше предложение кажется странным.
**Отмщение** [то есть месть] (чему? Д. п.) **душе** — возникает ощущение, что кто-то отомстил уже оскорбленной душе. Или ТАК и задумано по контексту?
Я бы написала **отмщение** (чего? Р. п.) **души** или **отмщение** (за что? В. п.) **за душу**.

Comment: Вообще не понятно, когда и на каком основании запятая может не ставится. Без запятой логическое ударение уже падает не на слово "вот", а на "оно": *Вот онО торжество добродетели и правды.* — тогда имеем подлежащее и сказуемое, а смысл такой: *Вот оно уже является торжеством добродетели и правды.*

Comment: Римма, да, отдельно предложение выглядит странно, но в целом тексте понятно, что отмщение предстало оскорблённой душе за её саму, за оскорблённую душу, а она отмщение созерцала и им любовалась) Но из приведённых Вами последних предложений - допускается и отсутствие знаков препинания? Всегда всё в великом и могучем двояко))

Comment: oleedd, расхождение в смыслах невелико - значит, можно и исключить запятую. Спасибо, Ваш комментарий тоже полезен.